# Parsing the result obtained from mochiweb_html

Tags: erlang, mochiweb

I would like to parse some content from an html file (no xml).

At the moment I retrieve the structure to parse using mochiweb_html:

```
1> inets:start().
2> {ok, {Status, Headers, Body}} = httpc:request("http://www.google.com").
3> {String, Attributes, Other} = mochiweb_html:parse(Body).
```

and the result is something like:

```
{<<"html">>,
 [{<<"itemscope">>,<<"itemscope">>},
  {<<"itemtype">>,<<"http://schema.org/WebPage">>}],
 [{<<"head">>,[],
   [{<<"meta">>,
     [{<<"itemprop">>,<<"image">>},
      {<<"content">>,<<"/images/google_favicon_128.png">>}],
     []},
    {<<"title">>,[],[<<"Google">>]},
....
```

What is the best way to retrieve from a structure obtained from mochiweb_http all the elements in the web page that have a specific tag with a specific class (e.g., `<span id="footer">`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [mochiweb_xpath](https://github.com/retnuh/mochiweb_xpath):

```
> mochiweb_xpath:execute("//span[@id='footer']",
    mochiweb_html:parse(
      "<html><body><span>not this one</span><span id='footer'>but this one</span></body></html>")).
[{<<"span">>,
  [{<<"id">>,<<"footer">>}],
  [<<"but this one">>]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your performance requirements.

The mochiweb result is in a 3-tuple form that could probably fairly easily be converted to input suitable for [xmerl](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/xmerl/xmerl_ug.html#id60740). Most of the work would be converting attribute names to atoms. Then you could use [xmerl_xpath](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/xmerl/xmerl_ug.html#id60740) to do some pretty flexible querying.

Otherwise you could code something less flexible (but maybe faster) to walk the tree.

Comment: true. just walk the tree to get what you need from it.

Comment: can you provide an example please? I am stuck :(

Comment: I like the solution provided by @legoscia better. I didn't know about mochiweb_xpath.