# Erlang: get information from parsed html

Tags: json, parsing, erlang, extract

My project is still encoding. But unfortunately I encountered another problem.

Recently, I manage to get html code from website with erlang and I parse that information in mochiweb plugin. 
Here what have got now:

```
    {<<"html">>,[],
 [{<<"head">>,[],[]},
  {<<"body">>,[],
   [{<<"table">>,[],
     [{<<"tr">>,[],
       [{<<"td">>,[{<<"id">>,<<"day">>}],[<<"Poniedzialek ">>]},
        {<<"td">>,[{<<"id">>,<<"temp">>}],[<<" -5 ">>]},
        {<<"td">>,[{<<"id">>,<<"wiatr">>}],[<<"13 km/h">>]}]},
      {<<"tr">>,[],
       [{<<"td">>,[{<<"id">>,<<"day">>}],[<<"Wtorek ">>]},
        {<<"td">>,[{<<"id">>,<<"temp">>}],[<<" -15 ">>]},
        {<<"td">>,[{<<"id">>,<<"wiatr">>}],[<<"13 km/h">>]}]},
      {<<"tr">>,[],
       [{<<"td">>,[{<<"id">>,<<"day">>}],[<<"Sroda ">>]},
        {<<"td">>,[{<<"id">>,<<"temp">>}],[<<" 10 ">>]},
        {<<"td">>,[{<<"id">>,<<"wiatr">>}],[<<"13 km/h">>]}]},
      {<<"tr">>,[],
       [{<<"td">>,[{<<"id">>,<<"day">>}],[<<"Czwartek ">>]},
        {<<"td">>,[{<<"id">>,<<"temp">>}],[<<" 12 ">>]},
        {<<"td">>,[{<<"id">>,<<"wiatr">>}],[<<"13 km/h">>]}]},
      {<<"tr">>,[],
       [{<<"td">>,[{<<"id">>,<<"day">>}],[<<"Piatek ">>]},
        {<<"td">>,[{<<"id">>,<<"temp">>}],[<<" 20 ">>]},
        {<<"td">>,[{<<"id">>,<<"wiat"...>>}],[<<"13 km/h">>]}]},
      {<<"tr">>,[],
       [{<<"td">>,[{<<"id">>,<<"day">>}],[<<"Poniedzialek"...>>]},
        {<<"td">>,[{<<"id">>,<<"temp">>}],[<<" -5 ">>]},
        {<<"td">>,[{<<"id">>,<<...>>}],[<<"13 k"...>>]}]}]}]}]}
```

And now I'd like to extract information about temperature, wind. How to make function in erlang to get exactly temperature in maybe list or add to json file, without any unnecessary things.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing the result obtained from mochiweb\_html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148202/parsing-the-result-obtained-from-mochiweb-html)

Answer (score 0):

Now I've got:

```
[{<<"td">>,[{<<"id">>,<<"temp">>}],[<<" -5 ">>]},
 {<<"td">>,[{<<"id">>,<<"temp">>}],[<<" -15 ">>]},
 {<<"td">>,[{<<"id">>,<<"temp">>}],[<<" 10 ">>]},
 {<<"td">>,[{<<"id">>,<<"temp">>}],[<<" 12 ">>]},
 {<<"td">>,[{<<"id">>,<<"temp">>}],[<<" 20 ">>]},
 {<<"td">>,[{<<"id">>,<<"temp">>}],[<<" -5 ">>]}]
```

Ok I got that:

```
[<<" -5 ">>]
```

How extract only -5 ?

Comment: You can use [binary_to_integer/1](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#binary_to_integer-1) but first you need filter out white spaces. You can use [binary:part/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/binary.html#part-2) `binary:part(ParsedInteger, {1, byte_size(ParsedInteger) - 2})`. Or use [bit string comprehension](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id81778): `<< <<Char>> || <<Char>> <= ParsedInteger, Char /= $ >>.` That `$ ` means ascii code for white space. Just like `$A` means ascii code of A.